# Доступ к аргументам командной строки из программы

Tags: c++, c++builder

Как сделать так, что бы файл (двойной клик на *МойФайл.мое_расш* моей программы открывался в моей программе? (как ассоциировать файлы я разобрался)
Как получить параметры запуска моей программы?

```
 start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASRD\asrd.exe" C:\Users\Саша\Desktop\newProg\Установщик\test_file.asrd
```

(Что бы вот на такой запуск в программе открылся test_file.asrd)

Comment: Необходимо получить атрибуты запуска программы (в которых указан к файлу который открыт командой Открыть с помощью-Моя программа

Comment: @aleks.andr argv[0] лежит целиком и полностью на совести вызывающей стороны и может содержать что угодно, а не имя программы.

Comment: Вы хотите получить путь к файлу который требуется открыть?

Comment: Да. Мне в программе при запуске нужно получить путь к файлу по которому пользователь два раза кликнул!

Comment: @trancer1019, Вы не пробовали информацию из моего ответа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно вашим тегам:

1. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.ParamCount
2. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.ParamStr

Или более обще для Windows:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

В нужном вам месте, например в конструкторе главного окна (или где ещё душа пожелает), вызвать, прочитать агрументы, произвести необходимые действия по открытию файла.

В документации есть и пример: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Seattle/en/ParamCount_%28C%2B%2B%29

Answer (score 0):

```
String prj_path = ParamStr(1);
```